# No Support for Oracle UDT in latest version of oracle.manageddataaccess.dll

Tags: .net-framework, oracle-11g, oracle-10g, oracle-12c

With oracle.DataAccess.Types we were able to integrate user defined types in oracle. But In latest version of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types UDT is not supported.
It seems that ODP.NET Managed Driver does not support UDTs anymore.

Affected classes and interfaces: IOracleCustomType, OracleObjectMappingAttribute, OracleUdt and many more..
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/intro004.htm#ODPNT8146

May I know the reason and alternative for the same?

My configuration :
.NET FRAMEWORK - 4.6
Oracle Version - 12c enterprise edition
OS - Windows server 2016

Is there any alternative way to use managed driver for UDT?

Comment: Madhuri...were you able to find a workaround?  I, too, am seeking for an alternative